# Disable the automatic sending of verification email creating an auth user in firebase

Tags: node.js, .net, firebase

I'm creating an auth user in dot net using `FirebaseAuthExtension.CreateAuthUser`. The problem is that this sends automatically the verification email and it is not customizable. I already have postmark to handle that, but first I want to disable the automatic sending of the verification email in Firebase and generate it in a different Node.js microservice by just passing the user email and using the template we have.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a `FirebaseAuthExtension.CreateAuthUser` API in Firebase. Can you link to where this API comes from?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.